# What is the NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER error in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, exception

While testing JavaScript code in Firefox 3.5 I sometimes get the following error:

```
Component returned failure code: 0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER)
```

I've tried Googling it, but all I can find are solutions to specific problems in other people's code (ie. "if you do this differently then the error will not occur"). But what I'd like to understand is: what *is* that error - what does it mean? In other words, what do I really know from that error and what do I need to guess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing specifically what you are calling, the error generally means you've passed something null to something that does not expect a null value.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error too using Coffeescript when my Callback functions were defined after my main function.
I just had to re order my functions to make it work.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the error by mistakenly trying to append an element to itself: elem.appendChild(elem);