# -moz and -webkit border-image problems

Tags: webkit, border, css

I have a problem with my blog: in oder to make a cool border I used some css commands from the moz-webkit and it used to work rather well. (at least in firefox & chrome, not IE)

These are the lines of code that I used to create the border are:

```
    -moz-border-image:url("file.png") 15 round round;
    -webkit-border-image:url("file.png") 15 round round;
    border-image:url("file.png") 15 round round;
```

This does not seem to work anymore and I have no idea why... 
The Errormessages I'm getting don't really help:

```
( NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER: Component returned failure code: 0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER) [nsIDOMLocation.href] )
```

oops, forgot the link to my blog:
http://life.wisniewski.org/

Does anyone know what happened or have an alternative to the moz-webkit CSS commands?

Comment: have you checked this http://css-tricks.com/using-css-for-image-borders/

Comment: I dont see  a problem. works for me in FF

Comment: There should be another background for the wrapper element (it looks like old paper) behind the text and images. Is that what you are referring too or do you just see the backround with the leaves?
It's not working for me in any of my browers. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's code you can use right away:

```
border: 15px solid transparent;
-webkit-border-image: url(fotoframe.png) 15 round;
   -moz-border-image: url(fotoframe.png) 15 round;
     -o-border-image: url(fotoframe.png) 15 round;
        border-image: url(fotoframe.png) 15 round;
```

### What have been done:

1. Fixed link to the image in `border-image` property (you had "fotoframe.png.png").
2. Added shorthand `border` property, as specifying just `border-width` wasn't enough for `-moz-border-image` to be displayed correctly. `transparent` is a fallback for IE, you may want to change this for some color.
3. Added Opera-prefixed version.
4. Changed image url to be relative.
5. Remove redundant second `round` value.

Comment: thanks a lot! The Border is working perfectly now, except it's not filling in the main body anymore but I'll figure that out. ;)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> I used some css commands from the moz-webkit and it used to work
>   rather well

Did it only stop working when you upgraded to Firefox15?

If so, this might help: [David Baron's weblog: CSS border-image changes and unprefixing](http://dbaron.org/log/20120612-border-image)

Edit/Update:

In order to fix my site and ensure compatibility, I changed this:

> ```
>  -moz-border-image: url("../_images/tributton.png") 0 4 0 4;
> ```

To this:

> ```
>  -moz-border-image: url("../_images/tributton.png") 0 4 0 4;
>  border-image: url("../_images/tributton.png") fill 0 4 0 4;
>  border-style: solid;
> ```

Comment: well, I'm not entirely sure but its very well possible - I'll look into that link thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Well border image is css3 property.To solve your problem try like this

```
#example-one {
    border-width:25px 30px 10px 20px;
    -moz-border-image:url("border-image.png") 25 30 10 20 repeat stretch;
    -webkit-border-image:url("border-image.png") 25 30 10 20 repeat stretch;
    border-image:url("border-image.png") 25 30 10 20 repeat stretch;
}
```

For more reference you can check this site.
http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

**Update**
  By searching your error code over Google I got this answer. Have a look on this it might help you out

[What is the NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER error in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780511/what-is-the-ns-error-invalid-pointer-error-in-firefox)

Comment: Thanks for the tip - however for some reason the browser won't recognize the functions anymore. So I don't even get far enough to try it out.
After I get the aformentioned error I get tons of warnings:
     "unknown function -moz-border-image" 
etc. ... I have no idea why

Comment: Use firebug to trace the css.

Comment: I am not entirely sure if this is what you mean, but what is confusing me is that the warning that I get ("unknown property moz-etc..." refers to a source file like this:
    http://s.ytimg.com/yt/cssbin/www-embed-vfl3RKADI.css
This is definately not the file where my css code is and I'm sure it wasnt like this in the past...

PS. firebug shows the correct css, but none of my browers (firefox, chrome, safari, opera, ie) will display it correctly...

Answer (score -1):

Instead of giving round u can specify the values as given below

```
-moz-border-image:url("border-image.png") 25 30 10 20 repeat;
-webkit-border-image:url("border-image.png") 25 30 10 20 repeat;
border-image:url("border-image.png") 25 30 10 20 repeat;
```

Please check the same.

Comment: You guys are not helping. How this can help to solve the problem?